# React Native got this error when i ran my code in phone using expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const ComponentsScreen = () => {
    return ( 
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}> Hello World! </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.Create({
    textStyle: {
       fontsize: 30
    } 
});

export default ComponentsScreen;
```

[Here is the picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHQKE.jpg)

Don't know what is the error here, help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Change `StyleSheet.Create` C to lower case like :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
```

will be fine.

Comment: Decide if the [answer is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and then Vote on it, and Accept it.